# Error in the Image Opening ( Using the Open CV C++ code )

Tags: c++, xcode

I am using this [code](http://programing-tutorial.blogspot.in/2009/11/image-proseesing-extacting-shapes-using.html) to detect the basic shapes in the given Image. But it is telling that unable to open the Image . Please help me. Please let me know if my question is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question needs a lot more detail than this to get an effective answer (e.g. are you doing this on a Macintosh or on an iPhone).

The bit of code in the sample you pointed to that's failing is this:

```
img=cvLoadImage("shape.jpg");

if(img==NULL)
{
    printf("Error in opening image\n");
    return -1;
}
```

You need to put your file in a place where the app can *find* it.

If you were on a Macintosh, put the file in the same place where the actual binary executable lives (e.g. "`MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp`").  Or change the path to be a precise place where you know for a fact the image is saved (e.g. "`/tmp/shape.jpg`" or "`/Users/sri/shape.jpg`").

EDITED to add what to do for iOS.  Try doing this:

```
NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YQpBE" ofType:@"png"];
if(str)
{
    const char *pathToFile = [str UTF8String];
    img=cvLoadImage(pathToFile);
    if(img==NULL)
    {
        NSLog( @"could not open image file at path %@", str);
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"could not find a file named YQpBE.png in the resource folder of this app");
}
```

Comment: Hi Michael I have written this code to open the Image but no use     NSString *str = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"YQpBE" ofType:@"png"];
    const char *fileName = [str UTF8String];
    
    img=cvLoadImage("YQpBE.png");
    
    if(img==NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening image\n");
    }

Comment: does your "`YQpBE.png`" file live within the resource folder of your bundle?  Also, is this on MacOS or iOS?

Comment: My file YQpBE.png is in resource folder and this is and iOS app

Comment: I've modified my answer for you.

Comment: sorry to say this Michael same issue . Error is could not open Image file at path '/users/...' . Eventhough I have changed the file to Desktop same error is giving

Comment: Wellll... the only other thing that I could guess it might be is that the png file is not being copied into your resource folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20865/discussion-between-sri-and-michael-dautermann)